# How do you include an existing javascript list inside your angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I incorporate an existing javascript list of objects into angularjs so that I can then use it in the controller?

```
var list = [];
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var obj = {
    date: rows[i].childNodes[0].innerText,
    action: rows[i].childNodes[1].innerText,
    ao: rows[i].childNodes[2].innerText
  };
  list.push(obj);
}

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.list = list;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access global javascript variable using `$window`

```
var list = ...; // GLOBAL var

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $window) {
  $scope.list = $window.list;
});
```